# Align subscript on baseline

Tags: xetex, subscripts

I have some subscripts with an additional overline. MWE:

```
% !TEX engine=xelatex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\newcommand{\textoverline}[1]{$\overline{\mbox{#1}}$}

\begin{document}
Ti\textsubscript{OC:110}Ti\textsubscript{OC:\textoverline{1}\textoverline{1}0}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Vertical alignment of subscript doesn't match]

The subscript is vertically shifted for the versions with and without the subscripts. Is there an easy way to align the subscript to the bottom/baseline of the letters?

Comment: Use `Ti\textsubscript{OC:110\vphantom{\textoverline{0}}} for the first subscript.

Comment: you could  try `\smash{\overline{....}}\vphantom{....}` where `....` is the same code. Smash makes latex ignore the height and depth of the argument. vphantom sets a height and depth of its contents (but no width)

Comment: Thanks, both work, but I chose to use the `\smash` command, since I can easily integrate it in my definition of `\textoverline` and, more importantly, I think that the alignment without the overline should be the default.